# Renderscript SigSegV crash affecting only Huawei Android 10 devices

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, renderscript, android-10.0, huawei-mobile-services

I have an Android app published that uses Renderscript to generate a Bitmap image.
For some reason I recently started to get a large uptick in the same error message on the Google Play Console (see below) that seems to only affect Huawei devices running Android 10.

I can't replicate the error on any of my hardware devices (however I don't have a Huawei device to test on), nor on the Android Studio emulator.

The error started to occur around the second week of March 2020, without any underlying changes in the renderscript implementation. I suspect this coincides with the rollout of Android 10 on some Huawei devices. The app has approx. 100k active installs, so I'd consider the observation that the error affects only Huawei Android 10 devices as significant.

Has anyone observed something similar? Any ideas on what the problem could be?

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

android::renderscript::ObjectBase::decUserRef() const
```

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.genewarrior.sunlocator.lite <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000036350  /system/lib64/libRS_internal.so (android::renderscript::ObjectBase::decUserRef() const+16)
  #01  pc 00000000000425f8  /system/lib64/libRS_internal.so (android::renderscript::ThreadIO::playCoreCommands(android::renderscript::Context*, int)+348)
  #02  pc 000000000002c2d0  /system/lib64/libRS_internal.so (android::renderscript::Context::threadProc(void*)+2108)
  #03  pc 00000000000ce1b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #04  pc 0000000000070ba8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Top 5 affected devices:

- Honor 8X (HWJSN-H)
- HUAWEI P smart 2019 (HWPOT-H)
- Mate 20 lite (HWSNE)
- HUAWEI P30 lite (HWMAR)
- HUAWEI Y9 Prime 2019 (HWSTK-HF)

Comment: If you don't have Huawei device to test it, visit your Huawei Developer Account and select from the main page the bottom service called "Cloud Debugging". You will be able select very fast Huawei device to test your app live(!) in the cloud.